# Flutter/Dart: How do you serialize private variables using json_serializable?

Tags: flutter, dart, json-deserialization

Is there a way to convince Flutter's build runner to include the private variables when serializing/deserializing to/from json?
If somehow possible I'd like to avoid making the variables public just because they written to/read from file... How do you handle this?

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'some_data.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class SomeData {
  double _someVariable;
  double _anotherVariable;

  SomeData();

  factory SomeData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$SomeDataFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$SomeDataToJson(this);
}
```

Comment: If what you want is immutability, you could use a freezed [https://pub.dev/packages/freezed] class with JsonSerializable.

Comment: Looks like it's not possible, no response since September... https://github.com/google/json_serializable.dart/issues/537

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old question, I know, but as this one comes up on top in Google: the library has now been updated to allow you to explicitly mark (private) variables for inclusion using @JsonKey(includeFromJson: true, includeToJson: true).

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'some_data.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class SomeData {
  @JsonKey(includeFromJson: true, includeToJson: true)
  double _someVariable;
  double _anotherVariable;

  SomeData();

  factory SomeData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$SomeDataFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$SomeDataToJson(this);
}
```

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74930701/4607142