# How to serialize private fields in json-serializable?

Tags: flutter, dart, json-serialization, json-serializable

**Minimal reproducible code:**

```dart
@JsonSerializable()
class A {
  final int _x;
  A(int x) : _x = x;

  factory A.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$AFromJson(json);
}
```

**Note:**

I don't want to make my private field `_x` public or define a public `x` getter.

Comment: I read [this post](https://github.com/google/json_serializable.dart/issues/537) but it's not using a constructor.

Answer (score 3):

This PR addresses what you want:
https://github.com/google/json_serializable.dart/pull/1256/files#diff-0acaf4c472e452d1e5d215a15fcd2266ccd02ab6abdfac0080c2fca845eb9096

You will be able to explicitly set `includeFromJson` and `includeToJson` on the private fields you want to include.

Example:

```dart
class X {   
  @JsonKey(includeFromJson: true, includeToJson: true)
  int _includeMeToTheJsonParsing;
}
```

It was merged November 30th. Latest package version is v6.5.4, released at October 25th. So you will need to wait a little bit if you want the official release. Otherwise, you can point directly to the latest commit if you need it ASAP.

Comment: Could you also write the code for the same?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Are you asking me how to use `includeFromJson` and `includeToJson`? Or to deal with the problem on the version 6.5.4?

Comment: Yes, I want to know how I will use the `includeFromJson` and `includeToJson`.

Comment: I wish you had provided the code as this question had a bounty. But since, the top answer is completely wrong, and it will get 25 reps automatically if don't do anything, I'm awarding 50 to you.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to answer you.

Since it is not yet live, I cannot be sure if this is correct, but I assume it will look like this:

`class X {
  @JsonKey(includeFromJson: true, includeToJson: true)
  int _includeMeToTheJsonParsing;
}`

Is that what you are looking for? Added same code to the response for better readability.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to make your private field public or define a public getter, you can still use a serialization library like json_serializable or built_value to serialize and deserialize the class, but you will need to define a custom toJson method that manually serializes the private field. Here's an example of using json_serializable with a custom toJson method:

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'my_class.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class MyClass {
  final int _x;

  MyClass(this._x);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    'x': _x,
  };

  factory MyClass.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => MyClass(json['x'] as int);
}
```

You can then use the fromJson and toJson methods to serialize and deserialize your class:

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  // Serialize to JSON
  MyClass obj = MyClass(42);
  String json = jsonEncode(obj);

  // Deserialize from JSON
  MyClass obj2 = MyClass.fromJson(jsonDecode(json));
}
```

Comment: I need to generate the `toJson` and `fromJson` not hardcode them.